# Mockito Test: verify static method was called inside fragment

Tags: android, mockito, powermockito

I have a fragment, that calls a static method from another Util class.

```
 public class DummyFragment extends Fragment {

    public void dummyMethodCall(){
      UtilClass.dummyStaticMethod(Arg arg);
    }

 }
```

How can I verify that the UtilClass.dummyStaticMethod() has been called in a Mockito test using PowerMockito?Below is my current test:

```
    @RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
    @PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*"})
    @Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 19, packageName = "com.dummy.package", application = DummyApplication.class)
    @PrepareForTest({UtilClass.class})
    public class FragmentTest {

    private DummyFragment mDummyFragment;

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mDummyFragment = new DummyFragment();
    }

    @Test
        public void dummyMethodCall_success() {

            PowerMockito.mockStatic(UtilClass.class);
            mDummyFragment.dummyStaticMethod();
            PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
        }

    }
```

The error log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name android.app.Activity. Reason: android.app.LoaderManagerImpl

at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:267)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:70)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassObject(Desc.java:43)
at javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassType(Desc.java:152)
at javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:122)
at javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:78)
at com.dummy.package.DummyFragmentTest.setUp(DummyFragment.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check it is called in your actual test could add a boolean static member to your UtilClass which you set to true in dummyStaticMethod(), then check that value after the call is made in your test.

If you just want to check it for debug purposes, you could run in debug mode and set a breakpoint in dummyStaticMethod, or add a System.out.print to the method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the test crashes by calling the static method because I am probably not using PowerMockito right. So I cannot follow the first approach :(

Comment: When you say it crashes, is that with the same log as in your question? If so it looks like the problem is something in your setup, on line 60 of DummyFragment. Or is it a new crash when calling the static method?